# How can i make an individual button for each user so when its pressed it toggles the isFollowingUser Bool and changes to following?

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, swiftui-list

Currently since its in a ForEach loop and i only have one State var, when i press follow they all change to following. I used a ternary operator to make the button color and text switch if the isFollowing is toggled. How would i go about making it toggle only for a specified user when the button is clicked. Would i just need to make 3 buttons outside the loop? When i used user.isFollowingUser.toggle in the button it tells me that I cant mutate user.

```
import SwiftUI
struct InstagramModel: Identifiable{
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    let username: String
    let userImage: String
    let followers: Int
    let isVerified: Bool
    let isFollowingUser: Bool
}
struct ModelPractice: View {
    
    @State private var users: [InstagramModel] = [
        InstagramModel(username: "aleedagenie", userImage: "AliImage", followers: 490, isVerified: true, isFollowingUser: false),
        InstagramModel(username: "nicole29", userImage: "volcano2", followers: 1090, isVerified: true, isFollowingUser: false),
        InstagramModel(username: "shamat81", userImage: "crashedCar", followers: 290, isVerified: false, isFollowingUser: false)
    ]
    @State private var isFollowing: Bool = false
    @State private var isShowDialog: Bool = false
    @State private var background: Color = .mint
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
            List{
                Section {
                    ForEach(users) { user in
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            HStack {
                                Image(user.userImage)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                                    .clipShape(Circle())
                                
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text(user.username)
                                        .font(.headline)
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Followers:")
                                            .font(.caption)
                                        Text("\(user.followers)")
                                            .font(.caption)
                                    }
                                }
                                Spacer()
                                if user.isVerified{
                                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.seal.fill")
                                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                }
                                
                            }
                            Button {
                                isFollowing.toggle()
                            } label: {
                                Text(isFollowing ? "Following" : "Follow")
                                    .foregroundColor(isFollowing ? .black: .white)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: 90)
                                    .background(isFollowing ? .white: .blue)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                            }
                            .padding(.horizontal, 44)
                        }
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("Instagram Users")
                }
                .listRowBackground(background)
            }
                Button {
                    isShowDialog.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Change Page Style")
                        .bold()
                        .frame(maxWidth: 140)
                        
                        .background(.orange)
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                }
                .confirmationDialog("Text", isPresented: $isShowDialog, actions: {
                    Button {
                        background = .yellow
                    } label: {
                        Text("Option 1")
                    }
                    Button {
                        background = .gray
                    } label: {
                        Text("Option 2")
                    }
                    Button {
                        background = .green
                    } label: {
                        Text("Option 3")
                    }
                })
            .navigationTitle("Instagram")
                
                
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct ModelPractice_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ModelPractice()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don’t use a screenshot with code. Instead [edit] your question and paste a [example]. See also [ask].

Comment: @koen got it, fixed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you are trying to mutate the **variable** of **closure** called `user`. `user` is a temporary variable which is not linked with your `users`, so you can't mutate it.

Instead you should mutate the `users`.

Here is my demo, try it out. Code is below the image:

[image]

```
struct UserModel: Identifiable {
  var id = UUID()
  var name: String = ""
  var following = false
}
struct DemoView: View {
  @State var listUser = [
    UserModel(name: "Lamb Chop", following: false),
    UserModel(name: "Steak", following: false)
]
  var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(listUser.indices) { index in
            HStack {
                Text(listUser[index].name)
                Button {
                    listUser[index].following.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text(listUser[index].following ? "following" : "follow")
                }
                .padding(5)
                .background(.black)
                .cornerRadius(15)
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show me how you would do this if it was in a ForEach loop

Comment: @ali9000 Sure. I just updated my answer for you now.